# Querying javascript objects using jQuery or other known js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

What is the best way to apply queries (such as regular expressions) on javascript objects to obtain a subset of some array or collection that follow some criteria, are there such plugin for jQuery, or some way to use jQuery or other known js library for this purpose?

for example:

```
var x=[{ firstName: "Tony",lastName="Mike" }, { firstName: "John", lastName="Jan"}];
var y = ????;//the first names of the objects in x where their last names follow the regular expression : bla-bla-bla
```

Comment: Are you talking about using regular expressions as filer for selectors? You can extend jQuery to create a regex-based filter. Here is an example http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-regex-filter/

Comment: Yes, but as a selector of objects but not html elements.

Comment: i think you shouldn't do such heavy operations on javascript objeccts, probably you should use some UI frameworks

Comment: Gotcha. I don't believe this would be possible with jQuery. You'd have to look at extending Sizzle ( http://sizzlejs.com ) which is the selector engine that jQuery uses behind the curtains. The best you can do is write a regex filter as i mentioned earlier, but obviously this wouldn't be a pure regex approach you're after. Not sure what other libraries out there would do that. I'll let someone else answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using jQuery:

```
var x = [
    { firstName: "Sakher",lastName:"Sawan" },
    { firstName: "John", lastName:"Jan"}
],
    y = $(x).map(function(a, obj){
        return /^S/.test(obj.lastName) ? obj.firstName : null
    });
```

Note that in some browsers you don't have to use jQuery to do this, as you can just as well use `x.map` in browsers that have `Array.prototype.map` (older browsers don't)

Answer (score 2):

It appears as you are looking for [JSONpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) or the like.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some frameworks like dojo for doing these kind of operations.

look at the sample grid

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html

you can do all kind of operations on that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can do it by JS itself:

```
var re = ...; // regular espression
var y = [....]; // input array
var x = y.filter(function(el) { return re.test(el.firstName) } );
```

In `x` you will have filtered array where each element satisfy your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) link.

```
var jsonArray = [
    { "user": { "id": 100, "screen_name": "d_linq" }, "text": "to objects" },
    { "user": { "id": 130, "screen_name": "c_bill" }, "text": "g" },
    { "user": { "id": 155, "screen_name": "b_mskk" }, "text": "kabushiki kaisha" },
    { "user": { "id": 301, "screen_name": "a_xbox" }, "text": "halo reach" }
]
// ["b_mskk:kabushiki kaisha", "c_bill:g", "d_linq:to objects"]
var queryResult = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
    .Where(function (x) { return x.user.id < 200 })
    .OrderBy(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name })
    .Select(function (x) { return x.user.screen_name + ':' + x.text })
    .ToArray();
// shortcut! string lambda selector
var queryResult2 = Enumerable.From(jsonArray)
    .Where("$.user.id < 200")
    .OrderBy("$.user.screen_name")
    .Select("$.user.screen_name + ':' + $.text")
    .ToArray();
```